# Creating a loop for a elements made of strings and integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a program and can't get the first part done.

```
while True:
print "1. Add an item."
print "2. Find an item."
print "3. Print the message board."
print "4. Quit."
choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
if choice == 1:
    item = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:")
    cost = raw_input("Enter the item cost:")
    elts = []
    elts.append([item,cost])
if choice == 4:
    print elts
    break
```

My issue now is that I need to figure out how to

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your code, so we know that you actually attempted to solve this problem on your own, someone will be more likely to help you.

Comment: sounds like someone just giving it a shot and is new to this. i hate when people downvote questions who are unfamilar with protocol. Frank - if you post your code and let us know what isn't working, we can help.

Comment: His code isn't working because `choice` is going to be a string and `'1' != 1`.

Comment: @IanAuld Actually that's not true. In Python 2.x, [``input()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to ``eval(raw_input())``, which would mean that if the user inputs ``1``, it will have a type of ``int``. ``raw_input()`` (which has the same behavior as ``input()`` in Python 3) always will return a ``str``, but ``input()`` attempts to convert the input into it's proper datatype. In general, one should only use ``raw_input()`` though. For example:

``In [1]: type(input())
1
Out[1]: int

In [2]: type(raw_input())
1
Out[2]: str``

Answer (score 0):

First task: make the process loop. Since the input to quit is `4`, simply put all your code in a while loop that breaks when `choice == 4`.

```
while True:
    print("1. Add an item.")
    print("2. Find an item.")
    print("3. Print the message board.")
    print("4. Quit.")
    choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
    if choice == 1:
        item = input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c: ")
        price = input("Enter the item cost: ")
    if choice == 4:
        break
```

Second task is to store all the items and prices that users input. I recommend using a dictionary. First, initialize a dictionary outside of the while loop:

```
d = {}
while True:
    ...
```

Then, add `item` to the dictionary with `price` as its value after you take in input.

```
item = input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c: ")
price = input("Enter the item cost: ")
d[item] = price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the choice variable and other variables below that in a while loop to keep it repeating and after you get the input needed, add both the item and price variables together? Not sure if thats what your exactly looking for but its as close as i could get hope it helps